# How do get ILPIP (PIP) from within a Node.JS application running ona VM in Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, dns

I need to get the DNS name (ILPIP DNS name) in a Node.JS application (an IoT gateway) that is running on a VM in Azure.

Background details.
I need this so the application can inform the web frontend where to open the socket.io connection to when the web based client wish to communicate with the IoT gateway.

I have been looking in Microsofts Azure modules for Node.JS but I haven't found anything that gives the ILPIP (assigned dns name)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`RoleEnvironment.getCurrentRoleInstance()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/serviceruntime/roleenvironment.js#L158) function in Azure SDK for Node.js, run the following code snippet in a classic VM:

```
var azure = require('azure');
 azure.RoleEnvironment.getCurrentRoleInstance(function (error, instance) {
     if (!error && instance['endpoints']) {
         //You can get information about "endpoint1" such as its address and port via
         console.log(instance)
     } else {
         console.log(error);
     }
 });
```

You may get the following similar info of role instance:

```
{ id: 'WorkerRole1_IN_0',
  roleName: 'WorkerRole1',
  faultDomain: '0',
  updateDomain: '0',
  endpoints: 
   { 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Rdp': 
      { name: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Rdp',
        address: '100.104.92.19',
        port: '3389',
        publicPort: '0',
        protocol: 'tcp',
        roleInstanceId: 'WorkerRole1_IN_0' },
     'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.RdpInput': 
      { name: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.RdpInput',
        address: '100.104.92.19',
        port: '20000',
        publicPort: '3389',
        protocol: 'tcp',
        roleInstanceId: 'WorkerRole1_IN_0' } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide something similar in Ressource management mode?
I get:
 [Error: connect ENOENT \\.\pipe\WindowsAzureRuntime]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '\\\\.\\pipe\\WindowsAzureRuntime',
  fileName: '\\\\.\\pipe\\WindowsAzureRuntime' }

Comment: This issue occurred on your locally or Azure environment?

Comment: Azure (westeurope)
Server is fine (ubuntu 16.04 LTS) running an IoT component written in node.js

Comment: Any chance that there is something broken in the Azure code?